# Number of points in a Bresenham's circle

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

The [Midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) generates a set of quantized coordinates for a circle of a given radius. The number of points generated for is of course a multiple of $4$ due to symmetry, but I didn't succeed in writing a closed formula for the number of pixels generated.

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

For the first couple of radii (starting with $3$), the number of pixels genereated is:
$$16, 20, 28, 32, 40, 44, 52, 56, 60, 68, 72...$$

So, is there a general closed form for this series?

**Edit**:

The series looks like it's given by:
$$a_n = 4\bigg\lceil\sqrt{2}\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\bigg\rceil$$
Though I can't see how this can be proved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid me.

Since by definition up to the quadrant midpoint, the number of pixels is a half quadrant is just:
$$r\sin 45^\circ = \bigg\lfloor \frac{n-1/2}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg\rfloor$$
Multiply by 8, and we get the result..